# How to reverse words of sentence in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, cpu-word, reverse

Example:
"This is an example" should be turned into "example an is This"
One character should be stored as information of each node.
After doing this I am able to reverse of the ENTIRE sentence(that is-> "elpmaxe na si sihT"). Now how can I reverse each word to get: "example an is This"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node {
    struct node *ptr;
    char info;
};

struct node *first,*ic;
struct node * insertn(int n,struct node * first)
{

    struct node *temp,*cur;
    temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->info=n;
    temp->ptr='\0';
    if(first=='\0')
    {

        return temp;
    }
    else{
        cur=first;
        while(cur->ptr!='\0')
        cur=cur->ptr;
        cur->ptr=temp;
        return first;
    }
}
void disp( struct node *first)
{
    printf("here");
    struct node *cur;
    cur=first;
    while(cur!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c",cur->info);
        cur=cur->ptr;

    }
}
void rev(struct node * p)
{
    if(p->ptr=='\0')
    {

        first =p;
        return;
     }

     rev(p->ptr);

     struct node *q=p->ptr;
     q->ptr=p;
     p->ptr='\0';
 }

main()
{   
    char n;
    int i=0;

    first='\0';
    ic='\0';

    while(i<7)
    {

        i++;
        printf("Enter element:");
        scanf("%c",&n);
        first=insertn(n,first);
    }
    printf("ELEMENTS OF LIST BEFORE REV:");
    disp(first);
    rev(first);

    printf("\n\nELEMENTS OF LIST AFTER REV:");
    disp(first);

}
```

Comment: Start with formatting your code, because it looks bad & unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Read each word and add it as a char array to a node. Then read your linked list from end to start. You'll get reversed sentence.

```
-------------------------------
+ *prev + "This" + *next +
-------------------------------

------------------------
+ *prev + "is" + *next +
------------------------

------------------------
+ *prev + "an" + *next +
------------------------

-----------------------------
+ *prev + "example" + *next +
-----------------------------
```

Now read from the end using *prev.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to store one word as information of each node.
Like this:

```
#define LEN 10

struct node{
    struct node *ptr;
    char info[LEN+1]; // the length of each word cannot be more than LEN
};
```

or

```
struct node{
    struct node *ptr;
    char *info;
};
```

Then you can use your rev function to achieve your goal.

If you don't want to change the struct of node, you should divide the sentence into words according blank. You can reverse each word first and then reverse the entire sentence.

Like this:
"This is an example" -> "sihT si na elpmaxe" -> "example an is This"